# Exe created with py2exe works on Windows 10 Pro but not on Windows 10 Home

Tags: python, windows-10, pyinstaller, py2exe, freeze

I converted my Python application into an exe using py2exe on Windows 10 Pro machine. It works fine on other computers (different from the one on which I have my development environment) running Windows 10 pro and even on the Windows 10 pro VM that you can download from Microsoft for free.

However the exe fails to even open (in command prompt it just returns without any error messages and doesn't seem to be doing anything) when I try to run it on computer with Windows 10 Home edition.

Are there any additional files that I need to package for this to work on Windows 10 Home? Can I install any redistributables from Microsoft?

Comment: Are they both 64 bit?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes both are 64-bit.